# akka-camel: setting URI endpoint in application.conf?

Tags: apache-camel, akka, typesafe

I have an Akka actor that extends camel's UntypedConsumerActor. I want to provide the value of its endpoint URI in application.conf instead of hard-coding, since the URI will be different in Dev, Test, and Production environment. I like to do this with pure typesafe config and don't have to bother with wiring in Spring. A sample application.conf would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read config property from the UntypedConsumerActor with something like:

```
this.uri = getContext().system().settings().config().getString("myendpoint-uri");
```

and in your application.conf define:

```
myendpoint-uri = "mina2:tcp://localhost:6200?textline=true"
```

Comment: Great! Not as nice as DI but works for now. When will Akka has its own DI? :-)

Comment: You probably want get the uri from the config and pass it to the actor's constructor. The prevents the actor from depending on the configuration